# How to resolve CA1820 for switch statement

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting following FxCop error:

> CA1820 : Microsoft.Performance : Replace the call to 'string.operator ==(string, string)' in 'Program.Main()' with a call to 'String.IsNullOrEmpty'.

```
 static void Main()
    {
        string str = "abc";

        switch (str)
        {
            case "":
                Console.WriteLine("Hello");
                break;
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm interesting question. If you look at it in [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) you will see the decompiled code as:

```
string str = "abc";
string a;
if ((a = str) != null && a == "")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

*The reason it is converting into `if-else` block is that, if the switch statement contains `5` or less then `5` case clause then it will be treated as `if - else` otherwise a lookup table will be used.(I am not sure about the number `5` but this is what is being shown in ILSpy)*

Now it is complaining about `a == ""` and here is the description why it is complaining about it:

[CA1820: Test for empty strings using string length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182279.aspx)

> Comparing strings using the String.Length property or the
>   String.IsNullOrEmpty method is **significantly faster than using
>   Equals**. This is because Equals executes significantly more MSIL
>   instructions than either IsNullOrEmpty or the number of instructions
>   executed to retrieve the Length property value and compare it to zero.
>   You should be aware that Equals and Length == 0 behave differently for
>   null strings. If you try to get the value of the Length property on a
>   null string, the common language runtime throws a
>   System.NullReferenceException. If you perform a comparison between a
>   null string and the empty string, the common language runtime does not
>   throw an exception; the comparison returns false. Testing for null
>   does not significantly affect the relative performance of these two
>   approaches. When targeting .NET Framework 2.0, use the IsNullOrEmpty
>   method. Otherwise, use the Length == comparison whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

this rule forces to use either `Length` property of a string or `string.IsNullOrEmpty` to check empty strings instead of checking with an equality operator ( `str == ""`).

```
 string str = "abc";

        switch (str.Length)
        {
            case 0:
                Console.WriteLine("Hello");
                break;
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

But I suggest you to check the string with IsNullOrEmpty before the `switch` statement or move `string.Empty` case into `default` case.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
{
    // related code section
}
else
{
    switch (str)
    {
        case "case1":
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
            break;
        case "case2":
            Console.WriteLine("case2");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `str.Length` may throw NRE, if str isn't initialized.

Comment: if switch statement is to be employed, I see no options Habib. Also, before switch loop, string can be controlled whether it is null or not. In the scope of question, I believe this answer is proper.

Comment: What you are seeing is sample program, in actual code business logic requires me use switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this in a switch statement. It is a bad programming practise.

You should use a simple if condition.

```
string str = "abc";
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
```

Comment: What you are seeing is sample program, in actual code business logic requires me use switch statement.

Comment: @AtulSureka I am not asking you to use if statement everywhere. I am saying that you first check whether string is empty or not. If it is not empty then go for the switch statement.

Comment: If you follow good programming practices then it says that you should check string is empty or not when it is received in a function. If it is okay then go ahead and do whatever you want to do. I am not saying that you should not use switch statement. You can use it once you have verified that string is not empty. If it is empty then handle it in the if condition.

Answer (score -1):

You should use string.empty instead of "" but that probably won't resolve the fxcop warning. Which normally I'd heed but in this case seems overactive, assuming you really want the pattern of switch/case with strings. If you can't suppress it for some reason (assuming the real switch statement has a lot more cases), you could write a special if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) ... in front of the case.

Comment: You can't use `sting.Empty` in case clause.

Comment: You can use string.Emtpy in a case statement, however it does not resolve the FxCox warning.